# How can I view error messages with pycurl?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I have the following pycurl code:

`curl = pycurl.Curl()

foo = StringIO()

curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, foo.write)

curl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)

curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, finalURL)

curl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, encodedArgs)

curl.perform()

responseCode = curl.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE)

effectiveURL = curl.getinfo(pycurl.EFFECTIVE_URL)

curl.close()`

When the command line curl command comes back I see:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Content-Length: 216

Date: Thu, 06 Jan 2011 15:49:36 GMT

Some XML Error Here: Something you are trying to do is not permitted.`

But I don't see this from pycurl.
How can I extract this alert/error message when using pycurl?

Comment: Is that error message part of the returned document?

Answer (score 1):

The response from the server is written using the curl option `pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION`.

In your case, since you are passing it a `StringIO` object, the response data should be in the `foo` variable: `foo.getvalue()`

Reference: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I knew I was almost there, just didn't quite know how to utilize the callback.